# Alternative to "Cannot read property 'range' of undefined " in onEdit function for google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on building a system in google sheets which will be used to track the daily attendance and production done by the employees on a daily basis. To achieve this I am using multiple level dependent dropdown lists which can be easily implemented using filters and mapping. Every time I try to run my code I get an error in the onEdit function block. 
The links to the google sheets I am using are as follows :
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1P0CcBWFNYqf2iSCXNdY5J_exdZfCVjltqDJvScRVQvo/edit?usp=sharing

The error that I get is as follows :

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'range' of undefined (line 14, file "Code").

The code I have written is given below :

```
var empWs = "Employee 1 Datasheet";
var componentsWs = "List of all components";
var firstLevelColumn = 5;
var secondLevelColumn = 6;
var thirdLevelColumn = 7;

var ws = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(empWs);
var wsListOfAllComponents = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(componentsWs);
var ListOfAllComponents = wsListOfAllComponents.getRange(3, 1, wsListOfAllComponents.getLastRow() - 2, 3).getValues();



function onEdit(e){
  var activeCell = e.range();
  var val = activeCell.getValue();
  var activeCellRow = activeCell.getRow();
  var activeCellColumn = activeCell.getColumn();
  var wsName = activeCell.getSheet().getName();

  if(wsName === empWs && activeCellColumn === firstLevelColumn && activeCellRow > 2){
    applyFirstLevelValidation(activeCellRow, val);  
  } else if(wsName === empWs && activeCellColumn === secondLevelColumn && activeCellRow > 2){
    applySecondLevelValidation(activCellRow, val);

  }
  }//End of onEdit


function applyFirstLevelValidation(activeCellRow, val){

  if( val===""){
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,secondLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,secondLevelColumn).clearContent();
      var filteredOptions = ListOfAllComponents.filter(function(item){return item[0] === val});
      var ListToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(item){return item[1]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(activeCellRow,secondLevelColumn);
      ApplyValidationToCell(ListToApply,cell);                                             
    }
}//End of applyFirstLevelValidation


function applySecondLevelValidation(activCellRow, val){

  if( val===""){
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,thirdLevelColumn).clearDataValidations();
    } else {
      ws.getRange(activeCellRow,thirdLevelColumn).clearContent();
      firstLevelColumnValue = ws.getRange(activeCellRow, firstLevelColumn).getValue();
      var filteredOptions = ListOfAllComponents.filter(function(item){return item[0] === firstLevelColumnValue && item[1] === val});
      var ListToApply = filteredOptions.map(function(item){return item[2]});
      var cell = ws.getRange(activeCellRow,thirdLevelColumn);
      ApplyValidationToCell(ListToApply,cell);                                             

   }
}


function ApplyValidationToCell(list,cell){

  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(list).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
  cell.setDataValidation(rule);

}
```

Comment: Do you only get the error when you manually run the script? 
Since it's an onEdit script, it's bound to run into an error when you manually run the script. There is no edit done, therefore there is no range, which will return the error.

Comment: @MichieltheTemp Yes, i get an error when i manually run the script. It sounds like you are suggesting that there is no need for me to manually run the script. Earlier when i had implemented just the level one validation, everything was running fine but when i began implementing the second level validation then the validations at both levels began to malfunction.

Comment: I tried making changes in the spreadsheet and not the running the script manually but it still gives me the same error.